# Work around for window.open in Salesforce1 Android

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, android

I created a visualforce page that can be opened in SF1 via a tab in the navigation menu. This VF page has links to reports and dashboards that need to be displayed in standard layouts (not the SF1 styled ones). To achieve this i created links like this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('/{!repObj.Id}?isdtp=vw');">{!repObj.Title}</a>
```

This works great on iOS where the report/dashboard opens in a child browser (inAppBrowser I am assuming). But when I run SF1 on an Android device, these links open the reports/dashboards in SF1 layouts within the app but not on a child browser. How can I achieve uniform behavior? I want the links to open in a child browser in both iOS and Android.